# ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 Ajax post Model to Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application, I want to post with Ajax some data to my controller. I already done this with ASP.NET MVC 5 and I tested the exact same code in an blank ASP.NET MVC 5 project and it worked, but with the new version I can't and I don't know why. 
With the Ajax call, I can go to the controller, the model is created but the fields are null (or false for the boolean). Here is my code :

script.js :

```
var data = {
            model: {
                UserName: 'Test',
                Password: 'Test',
                RememberMe: true
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Account/Login/",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Do something interesting here.
            }
        });
```

AccountController.cs :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            //if (result.Succeeded)
            //{
            //     //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            //}

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Identifiant ou mot de passe invalide");
            return Json("error-model-wrong");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Json("error-mode-not-valid");
    }
```

LoginViewModel.cs :

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: tried with `.done` instead of success?

Comment: This is not the problem. I'm successfully go to the controller, but the fields inside my model are null.

Comment: your DTO seems to be correct. hmmm

Comment: maybe the model binder is not binding the data from AJAX properly with LoginViewModel object. I experienced a similar problem due to the difference in current culture ( current culture was non-english and double values from AJAX were not bounded properly )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to explicit use FromBody on MVC6 if you are using json

```
public JsonResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
```

**EDIT**

I think you are mixing different errors. I will try to describe how you should make the request:

content-type **must be**: application/json

your request body **must be** in JSON format (as JasonLind suggested):

```
{
    UserName: 'Test',
    Password: 'Test',
    RememberMe: true
};
```

this is what you should see when inspecting the request (via chrome debugger tools F12) or using a request inspector like fiddler.

If you see something in the form of `UserName=Test&Password=Test&RememberMe=true` then you are doing it wrong, that's form format.

you don't need the `model` variable. if you see your request with a "wrapper" then you should remove it.

Comment: I already tried it but it doesn't work too. My viewmodel is created but it's empty.

Comment: Ok, I retested with this data :
var data =  {
                UserName: 'Test',
                Password: 'Test',
                RememberMe: true
            };
And it worked. Thanks ! :p

Comment: great, just stated what's needed to be in the request. glad you solved it :D

Comment: if it doesn't work for someone, please make sure that you are using a correct content type. it should be "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Has there been any breaking updates to this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement BindModel yourself! get the json string and deserialize to your entity.

```
public class JsonBinder<T> : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            //set stream position 0, maybe previous action already read the stream.
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) == false)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and set the JsonBinder to the post method like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonBinder<LoginViewModel>))] LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        //if (result.Succeeded)
        //{
        //     //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        //}

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Identifiant ou mot de passe invalide");
        return Json("error-model-wrong");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Json("error-mode-not-valid");
}
```

the other solution

I found that you could set DataContract to the class of Model, and set DataMember to the Properties of the class.

edit the class like this

```
[DataContract]
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and you should add library reference "System.Runtime.Serialization"

Hope it can works for u.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it (maybe with some sample source code), or just post it as a comment to the question.)

Comment: The [FromBody] attriubte works only with ASP.NET Core

Comment: Yes,  [FromBody] only exist in .NET Core, I found IModelBinder can do the same. @christophe-gigax

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
 var data = {
            UserName: 'Test',
            Password: 'Test',
            RememberMe: true

    };
```

Comment: Why it shouldn't be object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution, but it's still strange for me ...
You just have to remove the `content-type` from the request.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Account/Login",
            data: data,
            success: function (msg) {
                // Do something interesting here.
            }
        });
```

I've found the solution thanks to the watcher :) I watched the Request variable, and I found that Request.Form thrown always an exception. It said that I used a wrong content-type, so I just removed the `content-type` from my ajax post and it worked like a charm. I think that, for every ajax post you will make, you have to be careful that your Request.Form is filled correctly

[image]

**EDIT**:
This solution works only when you could post non-json data (very simple data), like connexion data. But if I want post complex data, like a list, it doesn't work anymore ...

Comment: If you want to use content type then don't use json.stringify.

Comment: I tested without json.stringify and with my content-type and it still doesn't work, fields were always null.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not MVC6 is jQuery. $.ajax() check the "data" and know its format so sets the content type for your, and also you should use $.ajax in a promise fashion

check promises vantages [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-1-9-ajax-promise-interface-advantages/)

and also select the form and just turn into to object, like

```
 $('.anyForm').on('submit', fucntion(){
        //you have the form in JSON format
        var data = $(this).serializeObject()

    })
```

and [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serializeobject) is serializeObject() method, it is not on jQuery by default.